# Can the minimum edge cover of a graph smaller than the size of minimum vertex cover?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Can the minimum edge cover of a graph smaller than the size of minimum vertex cover? If this is not true, then what are some counterexample?

Comment: Try finding both for the complete graph $K_n$.

Comment: I see. In $K_n$, the minimum vertex cover, $\beta(G) = n -1 $ as size of maximum independent set of $K_n$ is $1$. While the minimum edge cover is  $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$, which is indeed smaller than $\beta(G)$ when $n\geq 3$